# Python Append to filename

Tags: python, mongodb

I am writing a web form in bottle, css, js, mongodb. I am saving the files to a temp dir and then uploading them to a DB. Is there a way to check if a file already exists and append a number or something at the end if it does? What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a while loop which checks if file exists:

```
counter = 0
while True:
    if os.path.isfile(name + str(counter) + suffix):
        counter += 1
    else:
        filepath = name + str(counter) + suffix
        break
```

Where you have a string with full path to your file, without suffix!